# Convert facebook graph api explorer data to javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Can someone help me translate this facebook graph api explorer output to return the `fan_count` to a variable in javascript?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
FB.api(
'/me',
'GET',
{"fields":"fan_count"},
function(response) {
  // Insert your code here
}
);
```

however, if I wanted to print the fan_count to the console or save it as a variable would I just type console.log(response); where is says insert code here.